# Javascript XSLT frameworks

Tags: javascript, xslt

Are there any XSLT frameworks for JavaScript? What I am trying to do is parse some XSLT and partially render it on the client with JavaScript but some of the XSLT functions must be supported on the client side.

Any recommendations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking on Google I found this guide:

http://www.learn-ajax-tutorial.com/Xslt.cfm

In this page they recommend a javascript library for do this named **Sarissa**:

http://sarissa.sourceforge.net/

Try it out and good luck